# ctx.stroke() Processing Overhead

Tags: javascript

So I made a function, called square. This function is populated into a 2D array. Square has a public function which may be called and it just draws itself. Would drawing itself with ctx.rect(x,y,w,h) and calling ctx.stroke(); be more overhead than the draw function only containing ctx.rect(x,y,w,h) and calling ctx.stroke(); after the 2D array of squares are all drawn?

Comment: Deferring the render will give you some performance benefit and is generally the thing to do if your renders all share the same state (ie 'ctx.strokeStyle' are the same) But then you can get much better performance by drawing the rectangle to another hidden canvas and then drawing that canvas many times with the 'ctx.drawImage(' method

Comment: So youre saying, drawImage is a better way to go rather than using stroke/shape drawing? Thanks for the explanation!